# Tensorflow eval() - different results for (a/b).eval() and (a.eval()/b.eval())

Tags: python, tensorflow, eval

I'm currently running in a problem where tensorflow doesn't produce the results I intended to get. When I tried to debug the problem I noticed that up to a division everything seems to work out fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/87pm0.jpg
[image: strange eval behavior]

Can someone enlighten me what might be happening here?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to post a [mcve] (that means code, not an image) that demonstrates the behaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some stochasticity involved. Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random_uniform(shape=(4,), minval=1, maxval=2)
b = tf.random_uniform(shape=(4,), minval=1, maxval=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(a.eval()/b.eval())
    print((a/b).eval())
```

When `a.eval()` and `(a/b).eval()` are called, `tf.random_uniform` is executed and tensor `a` is filled with different random numbers.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right solution. I shuffled the tensor before for random sampling thus the different results. Thank you, esepcially since you managed to find a working minimal example

Answer (score -1):

This is because the `/` operator in tensorflow follows the Python 2 syntax and performs an integer division (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/div). You should use `tf.divide` instead. In general for any mathematical operation between tensors you should use `tf.operation_name`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue in my case, same results for tf.div and tf.divide.
But I assume this might result in similar issues.
As I'm currently struggeling to reproduce the error in a minimal case I assume that's the best I can hope for